# How to define a default function on a mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

After spending a few hours now on this issue i have resorted to SO.

I am running into `promise` pending errors on the following field I want to assign a default value for:

```
    friendlyId: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        required: [true, 'This is an auto-calculated field and you should not set it.'],
        default: function() {
            return mongoose.model(collectionName).countDocuments({})
            .then(count => count + 1)
            .catch(error => logError(error));
        }
    },
```

Yield the same error:
`Error: toggles validation failed: friendlyId: Cast to Number failed for value "Promise { <pending> }" (type Promise) at path "friendlyId" at ValidationError.inspect (C:\source\Togly\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:50:26)`

I have played around with a view different varations:

```
    friendlyId: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        required: [true, 'This is an auto-calculated field and you should not set it.'],
        default: async function () {
            let counter = await mongoose.model(collectionName).countDocuments({});
            return counter + 1;
        }
```

Is this even do-able? I just require the field to be populate with a default generated value on `model.save()`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a `.pre` save hook.

```
featureSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    var count = await mongoose.model(collectionName).countDocuments({})
    this.friendlyId = count + 1;
    next();
})
```

The big gotcha was, i was using `=>` functions and then `this` keyword was not binding to the document being saved.